# Show feeds in android

Tags: android, rss, feed, feedburner

I want to show feeds from a blog in a listview. It would be really help if you guys can suggest some tutorials or how to do it?

thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point you in the right direction, using standard Android SDK components.

Your solution will consist of several pieces - an HTTP downloader, an RSS parser (presumably the blogs have public RSS feeds), a `ListAdaptor`, and your `ListView`.

1. Firstly, you need to grab the RSS file from the blog. There are a bunch of ways to do this, I'd suggest  using [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) and [`HttpGet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html).
2. Next, you'll need to parse the RSS file you downloaded. For this, you can use [`XMLReader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html). Writing a good RSS parser is probably the trickiest bit!
3. Now you've got your data parsed, store it in a list and write a [`ListAdaptor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).
4. Hook the [`ListAdaptor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) upto your [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) using `setAdaptor` and you're good to go.

If this all sounds a bit complicated, there are various Java RSS libraries that'll perform steps 1 and 2 for you.

You may also want to take a look at the source code of [android-rss](http://code.google.com/p/android-rss/), and give [IBM's XML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html) article a good read!

Comment: Thanks buddy.. i am following this..but i am getting an execption..

07-16 13:21:34.240: WARN/System.err(3764): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'feed' not registered.

Comment: my url is like: feed://feeds.feedburner.com/somename1/something1

Comment: You need to use an HTTP URL, e.g. `http://feeds.feedburner.com/somename1/something1`.

Comment: Thanks man..i guess that solved the issue..now i am only left with xml parsing.. :)